# Reconcile commits with different hashes

Tags: git

Plot: I have a local `develop` and `master` branches. `develop` has around 90 commits ahead of `master`, spawning from ~6 months back.

I ran a `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --force --cached --ignore-unmatch media/*' -- --all` command that rewrote more of git's history than I was expecting, on both branches. This, because of what the command does, actually made a gazillion git operations, which left my `git reflog` useless.

I recovered the `master` branch easily with a simple `git reset --hard origin/master`, but my `develop` branch is in a really bad shape.

Now, obviously, the commits hashes between `master` and `develop` don't match, which makes git think that I have a gazillion commits to push and a gazillion commits to pull from/to my `remote/develop` (there should be 0 commits to pull, ~90 commits to push)

Is there a way I can make git "reconcile" all the commits from `master` and `develop`? It should be something like:

```
for commit in commits_in_master:
    tmp = search_by_commit_autor_and_date_and_message_in_develop(commit)
    tmp.hash = commit.hash
    tmp.save()
```

Edit:

If what I'm asking is not possible, can I (somehow) extract only the ~90 commits that weren't pushed to `origin/develop`, then `git reset --hard origin/develop` my `develop` branch and then apply those ~90 commits?

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch -u . '+refs/original/*:*'
git reset --hard
```

will put everything back to its committed state before the filter-branch.

Comment: All I get from running the `fetch` is `zsh: no matches found: +refs/original/*:*`.

Comment: You've got your zsh configured to reject things that could be wildcards but don't match anything. You can quote it so zsh doesn't go full inquisitor on you like that, I edited in the defense.

Comment: Indeed, zsh's config was the problem. Anyways, this really didn't seem to fix the issue, as git still believes that I have a ton of commits to push / pull.

Answer (score 1):

Before running `filter-branch`, Git creates a backup of all your current branch heads. They are stored in the `refs/original` namespace. You can reset your branches to point to the old heads again (having a backup of your full repository does not hurt before resetting your branches. Better be safe than sorry):

```
git branch -f develop original/refs/heads/develop
```

The `original` namespace has the same layout as your regular refs directory.

Comment: I get `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.`

Comment: That means that `develop` is your *current branch* (the one you have checked out). You can `git reset --hard refs/original/refs/heads/develop` instead of `git branch -f`, as long as you don't mind clobbering your index and work-tree contents.

Comment: Something is wrong with the name/reference. `fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/original/refs/heads/develop': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @alexandernst sorry, my bad. The leading `refs` shouldn't be there (it is already implicitly added by Git). Updated the answer, should work now.